# Why cant I click on this with IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using this [library](http://code.google.com/p/exsited/source/browse/trunk/code/scripts/jquery.editableText.js?spec=svn7&r=7) to inline edit the and this css

```
.editableText:hover {
    outline: 1px dashed grey;
}
.editableToolbar:hover + * {    
    outline: 1px dashed grey;
}
.editableToolbar {
}
.editableToolbar a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 2px;
    width: 17px;
}
.editableToolbar .edit {
    background: url("icons.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
.editableToolbar .save {
    background: url("icons.png") repeat scroll -16px 0 transparent;
}
.editableToolbar .cancel {
    background: url("icons.png") repeat scroll 25px 0 transparent;
}
```

here is the generated html

```
<div class="editableToolbar">
  <a href="#" class="edit" style=""></a>
  <a href="#" class="save" style="display: none; "></a>
  <a href="#" class="cancel" style="display: none; "></a>
</div>
```

and here is my jquery

```
 $('.admin .playlist_name').editableText({
   newlinesEnabled: false
 });
```

And all works well in all browsers but IE8....i looked at the Document mode and changed it from IE8 to IE7 and the javascript and css to edit worked.....Any idea on what the different mode is doing to cause this not to work

UPDATE........here is an example .. login to qa.previewplaylist.com with email user7@test.com and password English1

on the dashboard you will see an image under the Name tr " QA Again 05.12" and you can see when you click on it it allows you to edit ...but if you login and do the same with IE8 you cant click anywhere – The image below will show you what to click on

[image]

Comment: Are you receiving any javascript errors? What do you mean by it does not work?

Comment: So in all browsers when i hover over the .editableToolbar I get the dashed border but not in ie8...i get nothing.

Comment: yes i have my code in document.ready

Comment: this is a purely CSS issue, it has nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: Did you set doctype at the **beginning** of the document?

Comment: Where are you setting up the editableText?

Comment: yes i have the doctype set as <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: on the dashboard you will see an image under the Name tr " QA Again 05.12" and you can see when you click on it it allows you to edit ...but if you login and do the same with IE8 you cant click anywhere

Comment: It is kind of a pain to weed through your minified js. Could you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem?

Comment: Strange ...the jsfiddle works in IE grrrrr http://jsfiddle.net/v29ya/1/

Comment: Solved...the problem was IE and floating the image to the left

Comment: +1 Well glad to be of help. Sometimes it takes explaining your issue to others to solve your own problem. :P

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what your issue since you did not mention whether you are receiving an error or the site is not behaving as expected. With the current information, I can only assume that you do not have your jQuery code wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() {});`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.admin .playlist_name').editableText({
        newlinesEnabled: false
    });
});
```